# How can I modify a value type variable passed to a lambda in C#

Tags: c#, lambda, parameter-passing

I'm writing some simple code to user initialize objects returned from a pool.

I though I'd use an Action to do this on the Pool side and pass a simple Lambda expression as a parameter to define that initialization.

To make this work I need to pass the variables to the lambda by reference and I can't find a way to do this for value types (such as int or a Vector3 in Unity3D).

Is it possible to pass them by reference and if not then what is my next best option?

My unit test code for this is (let's ignore the problem of checking floating point numbers for direct equality :) ):

```
pool.SetObjectInitializer(
            (objectInPool) => { 
                objectInPool.x = 1.0f; 
                objectInPool.y = 1.0f; 
                objectInPool.z = 1.0f; });

Vector3 objectFromPool = pool.Get();
Assert.AreEqual(new Vector3(1, 1, 1), objectFromPool);
```

Comment: Why don't you just use a `Func<T, T>` instead? It would be simpler than using `ref`.

Comment: @JonSkeet If you're going to do that it'd probably be easier to just have a `Func<T>` rather than a `Func<T, T>` since you'd likely just construct a new one, rather than mutating an existing object.

Comment: I wanted to make sure no copies are made (hence the Pool :) ) but I think you're right that it may not make much difference in this case and I'll be able to just call return objectInitialized(...) from inside the Pool - thanks! :)

Comment: @RnR In general, pooling objects is *usually* not a good idea.  In the vast majority of cases it'll end up consuming more resources than just not pooling the objects.  There are exceptional situations, but they're rare.  Generally they involve objects that are *very* expensive to create, such as database connections, network connections, threads, etc.  A `Vector` takes virtually no time at all to create in comparison, and is likely not worth pooling at all.

Comment: @Servy I don't see how `Func<T, T>` and mutation are **necessarily** related. Maybe the original `objectInPool` object has state that needs to be retained - so, even if we create a new object, we need to copy data from the old one.

Comment: In particular, the ideas of pooling and value types don't go well together, really.

Comment: @rsenna Sure, but that's not what's happening here.  He's dealing with a vector and setting all three fields, so clearly *in this case* it'd be easier to just create a new one from scratch.

Comment: Yes, The pool is designed to hold reference types - this was just a unit test and as I'm new to C# and unity I incorrectly assumed the Vector3 may be a reference type and so had some unit tests written using value types etc :)

Answer (score 1):

`Action` an `Func` don't pass any of their parameters by reference in any of the overloads.  To have a delegate that has the signature that you want you'll need to create your own:

```
public delegate void RefAction<T>(ref T param);
```